# Appearence of seekbar and spinner in activity layout android 4.1.2

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-seekbar

My problem is the appearance of both seek bar and spinner inside  Activity. I tested in Android 4.1.2. This is what I want to appear like : [image: Pic 1]

[image: pic 2]

But when I tested it I'm getting like this:

[image: pic 3]

[image: pic 4]

When I created both seekbar and spinner in menu, they appeared as I want (As pic 1 and pic 2). But when I created them in activity layout I got them as last pictures. (pic 3 and pic 4) What should I do to change the appearance as I want ?

Comment: @Catherine Oh! sorry, it is typing mistake. I will correct it. :)

Comment: Okay, well, I'm not sure what you mean by "created seekbar and spinner in menu," but it looks like your test device is running a pre-ICS version of Android... is this correct?

Comment: @Catherine No I'm testing it in Android 4.1.2. The thing I mean by "created seekbar and spinner in menu," is when I create spinner and seek bar as menu items, they are appearing fine as I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theme you are using probably doesn't inherit from a Holo theme. In your `res/values/themes.xml` you should have something like:

```
...
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
  </style>
...
```

Comment: Would be good to have a look at your layout and themes/styles used. If you are testing on 4.1.2 and you see legacy Android component then it means you are basically doing something wrong with your styles.

Comment: yah! You are correct. It happened because of the theme.

Comment: Glad it helped! If you could also bump up the answer it would be much appreciated, thanks :)